# How to fetch objects from observable response in rxswift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am trying to fetch object array values from an observable response in rxswift.  And using the values i want to call another api as a nested observable .Can anyone suggest me a solution to solve this. pls..

this is my code snippet.....

```
_ = Alamofire.request("httpbin.org/get").rx.responseJSON() 
.map { value in 
let json = value as? [String: Any] ?? [:] 
let origin = json["origin"] as? String ?? "unknown" print(origin)
return origin } 
.subscribe(onNext: { print("Origin:", $0) })
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, do you want to nest another api call with `origin` value?

Comment: Yes..Can you please help me to solve this..

Comment: I have edited my first response to fit with your code, but the answer is still `flatMap` operator

Comment: Here I want to define an observable that emits the secondresponse. How i can write the observable ?? Can you help me

Comment: By using the flatMap , i'm getting the error "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate"..Can you help me.pleasee

Comment: Check my second edited answer

Comment: Actually this origin is a single value from a NSARRAY with multiple objects. And i want to call another api using alamofire with url and headers as parameters. In this case how i can write the Observable to get the response from the second api call. Please help me.

Comment: How can we implement this?? Anyone please help me to solve this

Comment: XFreire - Thank you ..Your code helped to solve my problem.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped you it would be nice you set it as a green valid answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To chain observables you should use `flatMap`.

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request("httpbin.org/get").rx.responseJSON() 
    .map { value in 
        let json = value as? [String: Any] ?? [:] 
        let origin = json["origin"] as? String ?? "unknown" 
        print(origin)
        return origin
    } 
    .flatMap{ origin in 
       // Here you use your other api call with origin as a parameter
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { secondResponse in 
        print("The 2nd api call response:", secondResponse) 
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Next time, please, provide us more info to be able to help you better :-). For instance, your code, your fetch functions, etc...

**EDIT**

```
func origin() -> Observable<String> {
    return Alamofire.request("httpbin.org/get").rx.responseJSON() 
        .map { value in 
            let json = value as? [String: Any] ?? [:] 
            let origin = json["origin"] as? String ?? "unknown" 
            print(origin)
            return origin
        }
}

func otherApiCall(with origin: String) -> Observable<YourType> {
    // Other api call using origin
    return Alamofire...........
}
```

Then:

```
origin()
    .flatMap{ origin in 
        otherApiCall(with: origin)  
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { secondResponse in 
        print("The 2nd api call response:", secondResponse) 
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion..But It doesn't help to solve the problem because i want to fetch objects from NSARRAY with dictionary values.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't share your code. Please edit your question.

Comment: _ = Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").rx.responseJSON()
            .map { value in
                print(value)
                let json = value as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
                print(json)
                let origin = json["origin"] as? String ?? "unknown"
                print(origin)
                return origin
            }
            .subscribe(onNext: { print("Origin:", $0) })  this is my code ,where response from observable given.Here the value is NSARRAY .and i want to get each values from each object in that NSARRAY

Comment: Thanks Henna. Could you please add this code to your question body (instead of a comment) ? If you do that, other SO users or even I will be able to help you better :)